# C - invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘struct ipheader’ and other errors

Tags: c, pointers, struct, compiler-errors

I am having some trouble with compiling my code due to these error messages (I suspect they are somewhat related)

```
In function ‘forgepacket’:
error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘send_tcp’

In function ‘send_tcp’:
error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘struct ipheader’
error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘struct tcpheader’
```

and

```
error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
```

every time i try to access `ip->iph` or `tcp->tcph`. Now I've gathered that the problem lies with the definition of `struct ipheader` and `struct tcpheader`, but I can't really figure out what.

I've been looking at similar error message questions as the ones above but I can't really figure it out.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>

#define VERSION "1.0"
#define PCKT_LEN 8192

/* Prototypes */    

void forgepacket (unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned short, unsigned short);
int send_tcp(); 
void usage(); 

/* Checksum */
unsigned short checksum (unsigned short *pac, int len)
{ 
    unsigned long sum;
    for (sum = 0; len > 0; len--)
            sum += *pac++;
    sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum & 0xffff);
    sum += (sum >> 16);
    return(~sum);
}               

in_addr_t sip;
in_addr_t dip;
int sport;
int dport;                  

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
int c;

/* Are we in root? */   
if(geteuid() !=0)
    {
        printf("Root access is required to run this program.\n\n");
        exit(0);        
    }   

while (1)
    {
        static struct option long_options[] =
            {
                /* Options */
            {"send",       no_argument,       0, 's'}, /* args s and r have no function yet */
            {"recieve",    no_argument,       0, 'r'},
            {"file",       required_argument, 0, 'f'}, 
            {"destip",     required_argument, 0, 'i'},
            {"destport",   required_argument, 0, 'p'},
            {"sourceip",   required_argument, 0, 'o'},
            {"sourceport", required_argument, 0, 't'},
            {0, 0, 0, 0}
            };

           int option_index = 0;

           c = getopt_long (argc, argv, "srf:d:i:p:o:t:",
                        long_options, &option_index);

                      /* Detect the end of the options. */
           if (c == -1)
             break;

           switch (c)
             {
             case 0:
               /* If this option set a flag, do nothing else now. */
               if (long_options[option_index].flag != 0)
             break;
               printf ("option %s", long_options[option_index].name);
               if (optarg)
             printf (" with arg %s", optarg);
               printf ("\n");
               break;

             case 's':
               puts ("option -s\n");
               break;

             case 'r':
               puts ("option -r\n");
               break;

             case 'f':
               printf ("option -f with value `%s'\n", optarg);
               break;

             case 'i':
               dip = inet_addr(optarg);
               break;

             case 'p':
               dport = htons(atoi(optarg)); 
               /* Add handling of bad/non number input here */
               break;

             case 'o': 
               sip = inet_addr(optarg);
               break;

             case 't': 
               sport = htons(atoi(optarg));
               break;

             case '?':
               /* Error message printed */
               break;

             default:
               abort ();
             }
         }

           /* Print any remaining command line arguments (not options). */
        if (optind < argc)
    {
        printf ("\nNon-option ARGV-elements: ");
        while (optind < argc)
        printf ("%s ", argv[optind++]);
        putchar ('\n');
    }

            /* check if all mandatory options are set and for unknown arguments */
            /* This really needs changing... */
     if (dip, sip, dport, sport == 0)
        {
            usage();
            return (-1);
        }


    forgepacket(dip, sip, dport, sport);

    getchar ();
    exit (0);

}

void forgepacket(unsigned int sourceip, unsigned int destip, unsigned short sourceport,
                 unsigned short destport)
{           
    /* IP header structure */
    struct ipheader {

        unsigned char      iph_ihl:5, 
                           iph_ver:4;
        unsigned char      iph_tos;
        unsigned short int iph_len;
        unsigned short int iph_id;
        unsigned char      iph_flags;
        unsigned short int iph_offset;
        unsigned char      iph_ttl;
        unsigned char      iph_protocol;
        unsigned short int iph_chksum;
        unsigned int       iph_sourceip;
        unsigned int       iph_destip;

        };

    /* TCP header structure */      
    struct tcpheader {

        unsigned short int tcph_sourceport;
        unsigned short int tcph_destport;
        unsigned int       tcph_seqnum;
        unsigned int       tcph_acknum;
        unsigned char      tcph_reserved:4, tcph_offset:4;
        unsigned int

            tcp_res1:4,       
            tcph_hlen:4,      
            tcph_fin:1,       
            tcph_syn:1,       
            tcph_rst:1,       
            tcph_psh:1,       
            tcph_ack:1,       
            tcph_urg:1,       
            tcph_res2:2;

        unsigned short int tcph_win;
        unsigned short int tcph_chksum;
        unsigned short int tcph_urgptr;

        send_tcp();
        };
}           

    int send_tcp()
        {
            int sock, one = 1;
            char buffer[PCKT_LEN];
            struct sockaddr_in sin, din;
            const int *val = &one;

            sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_TCP);
            if (sock < 0)
                {
                    printf("\nError: socket()\n\n");
                    exit (-1);
                }
            else
                    printf ("\nsocket() - Using SOCK_RAW and TCP protocol is OK.\n\n");

            /* Size of the headers */           
            struct ipheader *ip = (struct ipheader *) buffer;
            struct tcpheader *tcp = (struct tcpheader *) (buffer + sizeof (struct ipheader));
            memset (buffer, 0, PCKT_LEN);

            /* IP attributes */
            ip->iph_ihl = 5;
            ip->iph_ver = 4;
            ip->iph_tos = 16;
            ip->iph_len = sizeof(struct ipheader) + sizeof(struct tcpheader);
            ip->iph_id = htons(54321);
            ip->iph_offset = 0;
            ip->iph_ttl = 64;
            ip->iph_protocol = 6;
            ip->iph_chksum = 0; 

            ip->iph_sourceip = sip;
            ip->iph_destip = dip;

            /* TCP attributes */
            tcp->tcph_sourceport = sport;
            tcp->tcph_destport = dport;

            tcp->tcph_seqnum = htonl(1);
            tcp->tcph_acknum = 0;
            tcp->tcph_offset = 5;
            tcp->tcph_syn = 1;
            tcp->tcph_ack = 0;
            tcp->tcph_win = htons(32767);
            tcp->tcph_chksum = 0; 
            tcp->tcph_urgptr = 0;

            ip->iph_chksum = checksum ((unsigned short *) buffer, (sizeof (struct ipheader )+ sizeof (struct tcpheader)));

            /* Address family */ 
            sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
            din.sin_family = AF_INET;

            /* Source port */
            sin.sin_port = sport;
            din.sin_port = dport;

            /* Source IP */
            sin.sin_addr.s_addr = sip;
            din.sin_addr.s_addr = dip;      

            /* Tell the Kernel we're building our own packet */
            if ((setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, (char *)&one, sizeof (one))) < 0)
                {
                    printf("\nError: Can't set socketoptions\n\n");
                    return (-1);
                }

            /* Send */
            if (sendto(sock, buffer, ip->iph_len, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, sizeof(sin)) < 0)
                {
                    printf("\nError: Can't send packet\n\n");
                    return (-1);
                }

            else
                    printf("Packet sent to %d", dip); 

            close(sock);
    }           

void usage() 

{
 /* This is the user manual */  

    printf("\nTCP project %s\n\n", VERSION);

    printf("Usage:  -s -f <file> -i <destip> -p <destport> -o <sourceip> -t <sourceport>\n\n"); 

    printf("-s, --send,         Puts program in send mode\n");
    printf("-r, --recieve,      Puts program in recieve mode\n"); 
    printf("-f, --file,         Specify file containing steganographic message\n");         
    printf("-i, --destip,       Destination IP address\n"); 
    printf("-p, --destport,     Destination port\n"); 
    printf("-o, --sourceip          Source IP address\n"); 
    printf("-t, --sourceport        Source port\n"); 

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you didn't switch `send_tcp();` and `};`?

Comment: `buffer` is character array. Are you sure you want to do this ? `struct ipheader *ip = (struct ipheader *) buffer;`

Comment: @Mysticial uhm... now that you mention it haha. Well I sure hope it's that simple. I'll try again and report back. Thanks!

Comment: You'll have poor luck getting an answer if you simply dump your entire program into a question. What's the smallest program you can devise, cut down bit-by-bit from the real program that isn't working, which still shows your problem?

Comment: @Mahesh why not? what do you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The call to send_tcp should be moved outside of the sturct definition, of course:

```
};
send_tcp();
```

2) struct tcpheader and ipheader should be moved outside forgepacket

The code compiles fine now.

If I may add, I suggest you learn C and indent your code properly !

Comment: if you're working on Linux, you can use "indent" to fix the indentation for you, Good luck :)

Comment: The problem was struct tcpheader and ipheader were defined in forgepacket.The function send_tcp doesnot know about because the scope of those structures are only inside forgepacket fuction, By bringing it ouside you make the scope of those structures visible to all the fuction in the current file.Also I would recommend you to read "C programming by K&R "

Answer (score 0):

Just Add this header file. It will work.

```
/* Ethernet header */
struct ethheader {
    u_char  ether_dhost[6];    /* destination host address */
    u_char  ether_shost[6];    /* source host address */
    u_short ether_type;                     /* IP? ARP? RARP? etc */
};

/* IP Header */
struct ipheader {
  unsigned char      iph_ihl:4, //IP header length
                     iph_ver:4; //IP version
  unsigned char      iph_tos; //Type of service
  unsigned short int iph_len; //IP Packet length (data + header)
  unsigned short int iph_ident; //Identification
  unsigned short int iph_flag:3, //Fragmentation flags
                     iph_offset:13; //Flags offset
  unsigned char      iph_ttl; //Time to Live
  unsigned char      iph_protocol; //Protocol type
  unsigned short int iph_chksum; //IP datagram checksum
  struct  in_addr    iph_sourceip; //Source IP address
  struct  in_addr    iph_destip;   //Destination IP address
};

/* ICMP Header  */
struct icmpheader {
  unsigned char icmp_type; // ICMP message type
  unsigned char icmp_code; // Error code
  unsigned short int icmp_chksum; //Checksum for ICMP Header and data
  unsigned short int icmp_id;     //Used for identifying request
  unsigned short int icmp_seq;    //Sequence number
};

/* UDP Header */
struct udpheader
{
  u_int16_t udp_sport;           /* source port */
  u_int16_t udp_dport;           /* destination port */
  u_int16_t udp_ulen;            /* udp length */
  u_int16_t udp_sum;             /* udp checksum */
};

/* TCP Header */
struct tcpheader {
    u_short tcp_sport;               /* source port */
    u_short tcp_dport;               /* destination port */
    u_int   tcp_seq;                 /* sequence number */
    u_int   tcp_ack;                 /* acknowledgement number */
    u_char  tcp_offx2;               /* data offset, rsvd */
#define TH_OFF(th)      (((th)->tcp_offx2 & 0xf0) >> 4)
    u_char  tcp_flags;
#define TH_FIN  0x01
#define TH_SYN  0x02
#define TH_RST  0x04
#define TH_PUSH 0x08
#define TH_ACK  0x10
#define TH_URG  0x20
#define TH_ECE  0x40
#define TH_CWR  0x80
#define TH_FLAGS        (TH_FIN|TH_SYN|TH_RST|TH_ACK|TH_URG|TH_ECE|TH_CWR)
    u_short tcp_win;                 /* window */
    u_short tcp_sum;                 /* checksum */
    u_short tcp_urp;                 /* urgent pointer */
};

/* Psuedo TCP header */
struct pseudo_tcp
{
        unsigned saddr, daddr;
        unsigned char mbz;
        unsigned char ptcl;
        unsigned short tcpl;
        struct tcpheader tcp;
        char payload[1500];
};
```

Comment: Hi, Sangam. Welcome to StackOverflow! Explaining why this fixes the issues would increase the quality of this answer.